# How can I check if two elements/div belong to the same parent?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dom-traversal

Hi I am working on this piece of code for a shopping cart

```
$('.addtoCart').click(function() {

    //get button id      
    var cartID = $(this).attr("id"); 

    //get check box id   
    var checkBoxID = $('input.cartLevelChecked:checked').attr("id");

    //get parent id
    var levelListID = $(this).closest('li').attr("id");

    if(('#'+cartID && '#'+checkBoxID).parent('#'+levelListID)){
        $(".selectPlan").show();
    }

    //alert(/*cartID + checkBoxID +*/ levelListID);
});
```

Basically I'm checking to see if the check-box the user checked and button they clicked on belongs to the same parent then show a div

any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: could you please post your HTML relevant for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare `levelListID`, which you correctly queried, to the id of the checkbox's closest li parent, which you should query the same way:

```
if (levelListID === $('#' + checkBoxID).closest('li').attr('id')) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Got this one to work only thing the comer (,) before attr needs to be changed to a full stop(.)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
//compares the parent() HTMLElement (not the jQuery object)
if ( $(this).parent().get(0) == $('input.cartLevelChecked:checked').parent().get(0) ) {
     $(".selectPlan").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there, this should work if the parent is the immediate parent of both cartID and checkBoxID:

```
if($('#'+cartID).parent().attr(id) == levelListID && $('#'+checkboxID).parent().attr(id) == levelListID ) {
    $(".selectPlan").show();
}
```

Comment: that was one of the problems the LevelListID are not immediate parents of both cartID and CheckBoxID I was trying to use .parentsUntil() but didn't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can just go up to the `<li>` parent and see if the checked element exists in there, like this:

```
$('.addtoCart').click(function() {
  if($(this).closest('li').find('input.cartLevelChecked:checked').length) {
    //yes we're in the same parent
  }
});
```

This uses [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go the parent `<li>` then looks inside for the checkbox using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).  Then we're just checking that the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) isn't 0 (`true`) which means it found one checked.

Comment: tried this one the problem with it is once the check-box is clicked you can use any button to activate it thanks for though